# How to pull data from API and conver to CSV with VueBlobJsonCsv

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Do you have an idea how JSON data pulled from API can be stored as CSV with VueBlobJsonCsv? It is working when data property is initialized on component's mounted step but that could be to early and makes redundant request to API on page load. So I want on each click request API and pass it to "data" property.

Component looks like this

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <vue-blob-json-csv
      tag-name="div"
      file-type="csv"
      file-name="sample"
      :data="datafromapi"
    >
      <h2>DOWNLOAD</h2>
    </vue-blob-json-csv>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import VueBlobJsonCsv from "vue-blob-json-csv";

Vue.use(VueBlobJsonCsv);

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      datafromapi: [],
    };
  },
  async mounted() {
    //this works but this request is too early
    await this.requestAPI();
  },
  methods: {
    requestAPI: async function() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
      );
      const json = await response.json();
      this.datafromapi.push(json);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Just add an event listener to any button and call `requestAPI`.

Comment: @Aer0 yes, I've tried it but it works on second click as component first tries to export whatever in data property and then button's event fires and loads data into array (in this case datafromapi).